# iBeacon swift needs 'requestWhenInUseAuth' when detect Beacon?

Tags: swift, permissions, ibeacon

I try find the beacon, so requestAlways first time for get locationPermission, but I change to requestWhenInUseAuth, it can't find the beacon.
requestAlwaysAuth

```
locationManager = CLLocationManager.init()
        locationManager.delegate = self
        locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()

func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didChangeAuthorization status: CLAuthorizationStatus) {

        if status == .authorizedWhenInUse {
            monitorBeacons()
        }

    }

func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didRangeBeacons beacons: [CLBeacon], in region: CLBeaconRegion) {

        if beacons.count > 0 {

            majorArray.removeAll()

            for beacon in beacons {
                //                print("uuid: \(beacon.proximityUUID.uuidString) major: \(beacon.major) minor: \(beacon.minor)")

                let major = "\(beacon.major)"
                let num = (major as NSString).integerValue

                if !majorArray.contains(num){
                    majorArray.append(num)

                }

            }

        }else{



        }

    }
```

Should alwaysAuth can scan beacon?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to *monitor* beacons, you must request and obtain obtain `.authorizedAlways`.  if you fail to do so you will not get `didEnter` or `didExit` callbacks.  You can *range* beacons with only `.authorizedWhenInUse`, but the code shown never starts ranging, only monitoring.